# Unable to uninstall java

Tags: java

I tried to uninstall Java on my MAC OS Mojave (10.14) by running these commands (as it is recommended in the [documentation](https://java.com/en/download/help/mac_uninstall_java.xml)):

```
sudo rm -fr /Library/Internet\ Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin 
sudo rm -fr /Library/PreferencePanes/JavaControlPanel.prefPane 
sudo rm -fr ~/Library/Application\ Support/Oracle/Java
```

But when I run the `java -version` command on my terminal, I still get:

```
java version "11.0.1" 2018-10-16 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.1+13-LTS)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.1+13-LTS, mixed mode)
```

Any idea of why?

Comment: Try the command 'which java' and see where it is running from.

Comment: i am facing same problem...very irritating

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run:

```
which java
```

To discover exactly where `java` is coming from. Then depending on the result, determine how to uninstall that particular one.

For example, on my machine:

```
$ which java
/usr/bin/java
$ ls -l /usr/bin/java
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  74 Jan 19  2018 /usr/bin/java -> /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/Current/Commands/java
```

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines` and remove the directory whose name matches the following format:

```
jdkmajor.minor.macro[_update].jdk
```

In my case, I had `jdk-11.0.1.jdk   jdk1.8.0_181.jdk`

> java -version

Shows the higher version number installed.

[Reference of uninstalling the JDK](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/install/mac_jdk.html#A1096903)